# Why I am redirected to different plugin page url after activating any other plugins in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, redirect

Plese help me figure out this bug.

**Problem:** 
I had installed a syntax highlighter plugin named "[Enlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enlighter/)". But it didn't work as I expected. So I went ahead and deactivated and deleted the plugin files.

Now the problem is that whenever I am trying to activate any other plugins it is redirecting me to the "enlighter" about page. Here's what my url looks when I try to activate any plugins: http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Enlighter-About

When I tried to activate TinyMCE Advanced Plugin it is redirected to the above-mentioned URL. You can read the error message in the screenshot attached. However, when I press the back button I can see the "TinyMCE" plugin activated.

[image]
I want to know how to fix the problem so that it is redirected to its relevant plugin page instead of enlighter's plugin page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So after sharing this problem with "englighter's" plugin developer on the WordPress forum he asked me to clear the browser cache and php op-code cache.

So I resolved this problem by clearing all the browser cache and then everything worked fine for me.

Here's our discussion thread on WordPress https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wrong-plugin-page-redirection-upon-activating-any-plugin/#post-9302622